# input stream error

Tags: android

Here is a strange error I face, while trying to download a file, I need to open the input stream and then write data read into the output stream...The Input Stream does not work...there is no error while debugging..but it just seems to hang there and F6 on the keyboard does not seem to work....Have to terminate the debug session...What am I doing wrong???

```
 try{
        URL url = new URL(pdfurl);
        URLConnection conexion = url.openConnection();
        conexion.connect();

        int lenghtOfFile = conexion.getContentLength();
        Log.d("k", "Lenght of file: " + lenghtOfFile);
        //InputStream s=file
        InputStream s=url.openStream();
        InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(s);
        OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(file);

        byte data[] = new byte[1024];

        long total = 0;

         while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
          total += count;
          publishProgress((int)((total*100)/lenghtOfFile));
          output.write(data, 0, count);
         }

         output.flush();
         output.close();
         input.close();
        } 
         catch (Exception e) 
        {
         download_flag = true;
         String s=e.getMessage().toString();
         Log.d("k","exception occured"+s);
        }
```

Comment: have you added permissions for Internet in AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: yes..i have.....else it would not connect to the server...Am getting the length of the file.

Answer (score 0):

you could try an HttpGet request:

```
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
// Execute HTTP Get Request
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpGet);
content = response.getEntity().getContent();
```